# When Backgroud Service is Sending data to Web Service ,Popup window Not Working in Android

Tags: android

My application Having  alarm manager Service is sending Data to Ksoap Web service in Background.

my app is Having one Popup window is not working(Like Close,Save is Hanging), also can,t close the popup.

no interaction Between popup and background service, but Both fetching from Sqlite database data.

iam restarting the application then only Working.

if service is not Running Everything Working fine, Help me how to fix this.

Comment: can you post some code ?

Comment: this is most likely because your "Background Service" runs on the UI thread

Comment: How to resolve this issue, iam beginner for android

Comment: use a background thread in your Service or just use an IntentService

Comment: Thank you i am trying, any sample code for doing this

Comment: zillions of samples can be found by asking uncle Google